# Saving List of class XNA

Tags: c#, serialization, io, xna-4.0, .net

I have some problems with saving to a binary file.

I need to save my game information to a binary file and load it when the game loads. I have tried to make a class with all info that will be saved and then save it.

It looks like this:

```
public struct SaveGameData
{
    public List<Chunk> chunkList;
    public string saveName;
    public string playerName;
    public Vector2 playerPosition;
}
```

The problem is the list of Chunks... It does not serialize and the class cannot be serializable because it contains references to XNA classes.

My function for saving the data looks like this:

```
public static void saveGame(string mSaveFileName, SaveGameData data)
    {
        saveFileName = mSaveFileName;

        if (!Directory.Exists(saveFilePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(saveFilePath);
        }

        FileStream stream = File.Open(saveFilePath + saveFileName + ".dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        data.saveName = saveFileName;
        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

How do I save a instance of a class to the file and then read it later?

Comment: Well its not so simple to jsut call serialize and everything is done. Your have to correctly decide and make your class serializable. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) for more informations. One final advice, only serialize very simple data. If you want to serialize complex classes like Textures this won't work. If your XNA classes are Vectors and Matrix you should be fine.

Comment: Can you give `Chunk` definition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not issue while saving data.

XNA you easily save data of user or game details in files. But there can be issue with serializing stuff. Here are the different option I have used. You can choose any of it.

**Save as XML:** if your class is serializable (class with serialize attribute), you can serialized class to XML and write it own to disk. There are many ways of doing that using pure C#. Here is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286548.aspx) of it. You can select any of them

**Save as JSON:** if your class is serializable then you can save as JSON on disk using filestream as JSON is pure string and you can write data as stream.

**Save as Text:** I personally never prefer this as this file don't have any structure and reading back is difficult

**Save as Binary:** As you are trying here. Convert data as add as binary object. Biggest draw back for this is even you can read the data. It is faster than about option but in game there are very less moment when you actually need to do a IO operation. So, I personally prefer above options.

Please let me know if any more details required.